# Handle exceptions in lazy view transformation

Tags: scala, exception, scala-collections

I'm playing with scala lazy views. It seems that if we have an exception during a transformation, it's not very easy to handle. 
I tried to wrap with Try, but with no luck :

```
var v = (1 to 10).view.map {
  case 5 => throw new Exception("foo")
  case v => v
}

val w = v.map { w => Try(w) }

w.foreach { x =>
  if (x.isFailure)
    println("got it")
  else
    println(x.get)
}
```

Results :

```
v: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,Seq[_]] = SeqViewM(...)

w: scala.collection.SeqView[scala.util.Try[Int],Seq[_]] = SeqViewMM(...)

1
2
3
4
java.lang.Exception: foo
    at #worksheet#.$anonfun$1.apply$mcII$sp(tt.sc0.tmp:4)
    at #worksheet#.$anonfun$1.apply(tt.sc0.tmp:3)
    at #worksheet#.$anonfun$1.apply(tt.sc0.tmp:3)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$Mapped$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(tt.sc0.tmp:165)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:889)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:1332)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:68)
    at scala.collection.SeqLike$$anon$2.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:667)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$Mapped$class.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:164)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$3.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:193)
    at scala.collection.TraversableViewLike$Mapped$class.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:164)
    at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$3.foreach(tt.sc0.tmp:193)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(tt.sc0.tmp:8)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything; that's how views are designed.  They lazily call the method that throws the exception, but they simply *take the result* and pass that on to the method for the next map.  That's too late to do anything about an exception, which bails out of the control flow before giving back a result.

If you really need to handle a situation like this, you can make things *even lazier* by using an iterator and manually wrapping the `next` call in `Try`.  (Depending on the implementation, you might also need to wrap `hasNext`--for instance, a filter could throw an exception in something that is filtered out.)

```
val wb = Seq.newBuilder[Try[Int]]
val vi = v.iterator
while (vi.hasNext) wb += Try{ vi.next }
val w = wb.result
```

Otherwise, if you can redesign your view to indicate failure by returning a value that indicates failure (e.g. `Left(ohDear)` with `Right(yay)` being the good value; or simply using `Option`), it'll work more smoothly.

If you want to keep the laziness in the `w` level, try implementing it like so:

```
val vi = v.iterator
val w = Iterator.continually(Try(vi.next)).takeWhile(_ => vi.hasNext)
```

or simply write a custom iterator that wraps calls to the dangerous iterator in `Try` blocks.

Comment: Thanks ! Sounds obvious now... 
End the end, I implemented your last suggestion (custom iterator with a try in next()). Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

The thing with lazy views is that the underlying iterator is not evaluated till some `consumer` consumes it. And `map`, `flatMap` etc are not consumers, they are `transformer` which transform a `lazy view` into another `lazy view`.

Consumers include `foreach`, `fold` etc. Only when consumers consume the view, the actual transformation steps will be performed. So you just have to wrap your consume call in a `Try`

```
val v = (1 to 10).view.map {
  case 5 => throw new Exception("foo")
  case v => v
}

val w = v.map(_ + 10)

Try(w.foreach(i =>
  println(i)
)) match {
  case Success(_) => println("Successfully done.")
  case Failure(ex) => println("I tried so hard... but it doesn't even matter")
}
```

And... the thing with `Try` is that, you are supposed to wrap problem creators with it so that it guards any possible exceptions. So what you should actually do is to wrap your transform with a `Try`.

```
val view1 = (1 to 10).view

val view2 = view1.map(v => Try(v match {
  case 5 => throw new Exception("foo")
  case v => v
}))

// Now, your view2 is actually a view of Try's

// you can map it to transform again

val view3 = view2.map({
  case Success(v) => v + 20
  case Failure(ex) => throw ex
})

// now consume

view3.foreach({
  case Success(v) => println(v)
  case Failure(ex) => println("this one is a bad boy")
})
```